# Images not showing on Wordpress 3.5.1 multisite

Tags: image, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm having some troubles with my recent upgrade to WP 3.5.1.  Images and the media gallery are working perfectly on my main site, but on my children sites (including brand new out-of-the-box ones) I'm returning 500 server errors for images.

Freshly uploaded images also don't display although they are being uploaded to the blogs.dir library (confirmed via FTP).

Here's an example of an image on my site that exists on the server but isn't loading correctly:
http://mysarasotashortsale.com/files/2011/01/Alex-Krumm-2-Web.jpg

Has anyone else had this trouble in the last upgrade?  How did you fix it?

FYI, here's my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem after the update to 3.5.1 but looking at your .htaccess file you seem to be missing something.

```
...
# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
...
```